# Replace one ggplot default theme element with an element from another default theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really like everything about `ggplot2`'s `ggtheme`'s `theme_fivethirtyeight()` except for the fact that it hides all axis titles.

How can I use `theme_fivethirtyeight()` but tell it to inherit the axis title specification from another theme?

Comment: `theme_fivethirtyeight() + theme(axis.title=element_text())`.  If you type `theme_fivethirtyeight` in the console, you'll see the code for `theme_fivethirtyeight()`. Note in that code the statement `axis.title=element_blank()`. You just need to override that as in the code above.

Comment: @Lucas Spangher:  Does the example below answer your question?  Please let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: No -- it does! Thank you. I'm sorry for the tardiness -- I wasn't expecting such a fast reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved many ways.  The shortest might be to override the `element_text` argument as @eipi10 suggests.  This would need to be repeated for each individual plot.

Another way is to create your own custom theme based on an existing theme.  **The benefit of this approach is that you can reuse your theme once you get it exactly how you like it.**  Here is an example using `theme_fivethiryeight()`.

The key part is:

```
   mytheme <- theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(colour = "black" ))
```

Creating some dummy data to work with:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggthemes")
# make the results reproducible
set.seed(5117)  

start_date <- as.Date("2015-01-01") 
end_date <- as.Date("2017-06-10")

# the by=7 makes it one observation per week (adjust as needed)
dates <- seq(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = 7)
val1 <- rnorm(length(dates), mean = 12.5, sd = 3)

qnt <- quantile(val1, c(.05, .25, .75, .95))

mock <- data.frame(myDate = dates, val1)

p <- ggplot(data = mock, mapping = aes(x = myDate, y = val1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[1], colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[4], colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[2], colour = "lightgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[3], colour = "lightgreen") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 month", date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Here is adding the original `theme_fivethirtyeight()` for reference:

`p + theme_fivethirtyeight()`

[image: original theme plot]

Creating a custom theme:

```
mytheme <- theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(colour = "black" ))
```

Applying the custom theme to the original plot:

```
p + mytheme
```

[image: custom theme plot]

You can type the theme name (*without the* "()") at the command prompt to get an idea of what other options are available to customize.  Here I highlighted the `axis.title = element_blank()` that was replaced:

[image: theme_code]

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough and complete answer. In retrospect, it's obvious -- sorry -- but I wasn't sure which element to replace, and what would happen to the other parts of the text element (size, angle, etc) all that were inherited as NULL from theme_fivethirtyeight(). Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%+replace%` to replace the specific theme elements you want. For any theme you can retrieve the theme element by using `[[`. So if you wanted the theme for `axis.title` from `theme_gdocs` you would do: `theme_gdocs()[["axis.title"]]`. This should work for you:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(hp, cyl)) + 
                 theme_fivethirtyeight() %+replace% theme(axis.title = theme_gdocs()[["axis.title"]],
                                                         axis.title.x = theme_gdocs()[["axis.title.x"]],
                                                         axis.title.y = theme_gdocs()[["axis.title.y"]])
```

[image]

I used `theme_gdocs` as an example but you can replace that with whatever theme you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot_merge_styles <- function(theme, ...) {
  elements <- lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], function(x) eval(parse(text=deparse(x))))
  for (element in names(elements)) {
    if (element != 'theme') {
      theme[[element]] <- elements[[element]]
    }
  }
  
  return(theme)
}
```

Then you can specify certain design attributes and merge them together with other styles.

For instance, I enjoy the `theme_minimal()`'s design on `plot.title`, except that I want it to be coloured gray instead of it's ordinary black. Then by running the following code, all `plot.title` properties are preserved except for colour which is being replaced:

```
plot <- 
  ... +
  theme(plot.title = ggplot_merge_styles(theme_minimal()[['plot.title']], colour = "#6f7170"))
```